# How to make a login through google account?

Tags: authentication, html

How do you merge login on your webpage with google or other e-mail account (i.e., like on SO)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [OpenId](http://openid.net/add-openid)

Comment: But is it free?Can i get every contacts of a person who log-in to my account through Openid??

Comment: Yes, it is free. No, you can't get the contacts, it is just a log in system. Look at OAuth for access to contact data.

Answer (score 1):

Using Either OpenID or OpenID+OAuth you can implement google login as well as others providers(Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Yahoo, etc.).

Take a look on this links.

http://openid.net/add-openid/

http://openid.net/developers/

http://oauth.net/about/

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html